# JavaScript Hash Tag Parsing Function

Tags: javascript, regex, twitter

I already had two regex functions to parse url's and replies from a json twitter response but I tried to extend it to parse hash tags aswell but I am getting `undefined` displayed in palce of the hashtag:

```
// process links, reply and hash tags
tweet = tweet.replace(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig, function(url) {
        return '<a href="'+url+'">'+url+'</a>';
    }).replace(/B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
        return  reply.charAt(0)+'<a href="http://twitter.com/'+reply.substring(1)+'">'+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
    }).replace(/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g), function(hash) {
        return '<a class="hashtag" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/#search?q='+$1+'">#'+$1+'</a>';
    };
```

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what is the content of `tweet`?

Comment: tweet is `another spammy tweet #test` and output is `another spammy tweet undefined`

Comment: why are you not using `hash` variable?

Comment: `$1` isn't a special variable, it's a common name for the parameter passed in `string.replace`

Answer (score 1):

The function in the last replace takes a hash parameter, use that in your return instead of $1

Answer (score 1):

The **$1** variable is undefined, replace it with **hash.substring(1)**

Also, you need to close the last function call after the anonymous function declaration.

```
tweet = tweet.replace(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig, function(url) {
    return '<a href="'+url+'">'+url+'</a>';
}).replace(/B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
    return  reply.charAt(0)+'<a href="http://twitter.com/'+reply.substring(1)+'">'+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
}).replace(/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g, function(hash) {
    return '<a class="hashtag" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/#search?q='+hash.substring(1)+'">#'+hash.substring(1)+'</a>';
});
```

Comment: got it, thank you, i had my closing bracket in after the regex aswell when it should have been at the end of the function